# Base Activity extending Activity ViewBinding Crash

Tags: java, android, android-viewbinding

I have  Base Activity extends My all other activities. The Base Activity has features like toolbar, progress bar, and other logic methods that are similar across the activity

After Migrating from ButterKnife to ViewBinding The child activity that is extended from the parent base is not able to access the methods in it And the app gets crashed.

Below is Base Activity Code

```
pubic class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private ActivityBaseBinding activityBaseBinding;

 

    @Override
    public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
        activityBaseBinding = ActivityBaseBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());

        View  view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, activityBaseBinding.container, false);

        if (layoutResID == R.layout.activity_home) {
            activityBaseBinding.toolbarTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else if (layoutResID == R.layout.activity_my_account) {
            activityBaseBinding.toolbarTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            activityBaseBinding.toolbarTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        activityBaseBinding.container.addView(view);
        setContentView(activityBaseBinding.getRoot());
        activityBaseBinding.imgBackArrow.setOnClickListener(v -> onBackPressed());

    }
```

If I try to access the toolbar in the base from the child activity this is the error I get

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{com.iowave.scheduler/com.example.myaccount.views.MyAccount}:
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field
> 'com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
> com.example.databinding.ActivityBaseBinding.toolbarTitle' on
> a null object reference

This is the code of my child activity

```
public class MyAccount extends BaseActivity implements MyAccountImpl {

    private NavController navController;


    private ActivityMyAccountBinding activityMyAccountBinding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        activityMyAccountBinding = ActivityMyAccountBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        View view = activityMyAccountBinding.getRoot();
        setContentView(view);
             }
}
```

From what I understand the view binding is only binding the child view and removing all other bindings from the background.

Comment: do you realize you overrode `setContentView(int)` but used `setContentView(view)`? not to mention that this design is questionable at best. I think every `xml` file has its own binding class, and you can't use one activity's for another's. Binding classes don't care about whether your activity inherits another, they are made from scratch for each `xml` file.

Comment: Yes, that's true but this decreases the code thus making the app more memory friendly. This architecture provides me with reusable code in multiple activities .@Ace if u can suggest me a better approach please do share I would like to check it out. Thank You

Comment: Extending base activity is not the problem, reading the base activity's xml bindings is. You can keep the base activity and its subclasses, but don't make an xml file for it. Use [`<include>`](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts)s in your xml files for layout reusability.

Comment: So u are saying read all methods from child one and use base activity for other things like force logout stuff . This will then be like using the same code in all the activities.      
 In this case,I have to make one activity app then.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your first statement. I said before that you can extend a base activity for shared logic, just don't expect its `xml` layout to be magically shared too. Also, yeah, single activity apps (with new navigation, viewModel, etc) are good. but don't _force_ "every single fragment" in if they shouldn't be.

Comment: Partially I Agree, However, I was looking for a solution to fix the issue.  As I don't have many Activities it also makes sense to scrap the layout in the base activity as u said and use include to add toolbar and progress bar. Thank you.

Comment: the solution to your specific problem above is to fix the unused override + don't give an `xml` file to a `BaseActivity`, especially "don't expect it to be inherited" too.

Comment: How did you solve? I am facing the same problem without butterknife.

Answer (score 1):

Use this approach for base activity patterns.

```
    abstract class  BaseActivity1<Binding extends ViewBinding> extends AppCompatActivity {

    Binding binding;

    abstract  Binding getBinding();

    void  initBinding(){
        binding=getBinding();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.initBinding();
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
    }  
}
```

then

```
class MainActivity extends BaseActivity1<ActivityMainBinding>{
    @Override
    ActivityMainBinding getBinding(){
        return ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be solve your problem:

I just migrated the project from Butterknife to ViewBinding and face problems related implementing encapsulated activities view into base activity' container, too. Before implementing ViewBinding, I was using  `getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, activityContainer, true);` where `layoutResID` was id of encapsulated activities' xml layout (R.layout.activity_main) in BaseActivity so I could inflate encapsulated activities' xml inside `activityContainer` which is corresponding to FrameLayout inside BaseActivity's xml. But then I figure out that, with ViewBinding, there is no ViewGroup id (xml) but View. So I couldn't use `getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, activityContainer, true);` because layoutResID is a ViewGroup id, not View. Here is how I solved.:

```
abstract class BaseActivity<VB : ViewBinding> : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var _binding: VB? = null
    
    val childActivityBinding: VB
            get() = _binding as VB

    abstract fun inflateLayout(
        parent: FrameLayout,
        inflater: LayoutInflater
    ): VB

    lateinit var baseActivityBinding: ActivityBaseBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        baseActivityBinding = ActivityBaseBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        _binding = inflateLayout(baseActivityBinding.root.layout_container, layoutInflater)

        val coordinatorLayout = baseActivityBinding.root
        .
        .// some base activity processes like setting Snackbar etc.
        val snack = coordinatorLayout.snack
        .

        super.setContentView(coordinatorLayout)
    }
}
```

Here is Main Activity: [ in Java :) ]

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity<ActivityMainBinding> {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ActivityMainBinding inflateLayout(@NonNull FrameLayout parent, @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater) {
        return ActivityMainBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, true);
    }
}
```

With this approach, I was able to inflate the encapsulated activities view inside base activity like a subview.